# .NET Compiler Platform: Not Working

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, roslyn

I have Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.5.5 installed (latest version of the date apparently). However, I can't use .NET Compiler Platform SDK. I used to have it as an extension and now it just doesn't work with a warning. The warning says: "This extension is disabled because the installed version is incompatible with Visual Studio. Please go to the Updates tab to get the latest version of this extension to enable it". There's nothing on the Updates tab.

[image]

Any idea how I could fix this?

Comment: It will work if we install from Individual component of Visual studio installer>> Modify as mentioned by @idubnori

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been tracked as an issue on [dotnet/roslyn-sdk](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk/issues/75).

**Workaround**

1. Run Visual Studio Installer
2. Hit Modify
3. Select the Individual components tab
4. Check the box for .NET Compiler Platform SDK